# Fancyhdr's extra dot in header for section title: How to remove?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, titlesec

I like to use Arabic numbers ***with a dot*** in front of section titles. So, for example `1. My section title` instead of `1 My section title` or something else. To achieve this, the syntactically simple option

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
```

works like a charm. The dot also appears in the table of contents, which is great. Next, I load the [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package ([documentation](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)). **The aim** is to obtain the identical format in `fancyhdr`'s fancy header. By default (when `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}` is in use), it gives **two dots** instead of the desired one dot, so `1.. My section title` instead of `1. My section title`. This is the *only thing* I would like to change.

---

After reading a little bit of the documentation, I guessed that

`\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}`

would work. Compiling with Overleaf, this did not help. Compiling instead with my local (more updated) distribution the problem was solved.

- Is this a reasonable/safe/canonical way to solve the problem?

("Safe" – likely to work in the future, not breaking something important in the background)

- If not, what is a better/alternative solution? (Minimally invasive, syntactically simple solution is preferred)

---

MWE (uncomment for my attempted solution):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} <-- uncomment this for my attempt

\begin{document}

    \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\tableofcontents}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \chapter{My chapter title}
        \section{My chapter title}
            \pagebreak
            Why two dots in fancy header here?

\end{document}
```

**Output of page 5 (Overleaf, commented or uncommented – no difference):**

[image: Output of page 5 (Overleaf]

**Output of page 5 (local, commented):**

[image: Output of page 5 (local, commented)]

**Output of page 5 (local, uncommented):**

[image: Output of page 5 (local, uncommented)]

> I am running `pdflatex` 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MikTeX 21.3), and every package in my local distrubution was updated on 28/04/2021.

Comment: @Oni That removes the dot from everywhere, not just ``fancyhdr``'s header.

Comment: Remember that \thesection is often used for many things, not just the section title or the TOC.  (If you put a \label after \section, \ref will use \thesection.)

Comment: @Linear Christmas Thank for your feedback. I updated my answer. Werner`s is the best.

Comment: @Linear Christmas Please check my re-updated answer including the subsections. I suggest that you update your question to include the added requirements (TOC  and subsection).

Comment: @SimonDispa Thanks for the update, I'll check it in a bit. Wrt TOC: the requirements are there, even if a bit (or a lot) between the lines. I wrote: "The dot also appears in the table of contents, which is great", and "[fancyheader] is the only thing I would like to change". As regards to subsections (if you are referring to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595713/fancyhdrs-extra-dot-in-header-for-section-title-how-to-remove?noredirect=1#comment1494536_595719)), that was not so much directed at you as it was at future readers. That isn't part of OP, you are correct.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for the comment, I missed it at first. Yes, you are correct, I didn't consider that. I just assumed it was the "default assumption" that if the user wants to have dots after titles, they have to add it themselves. And that "usual packages" do not try to add a dot themselves. My mistake. :) And, yes: for labelling things, it is useful to have an option without dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) you have two things you need to update - the sectional unit number in the section title (`\@seccntformat`) and what is printed in the ToC (`\cftsecafternsum` from [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\makeatletter
% Add dot after sectional unit number (for \section, \subsection, ...)
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}% Remove chapter number from section number
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}% Add dot after section number in ToC

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter title}
\section{My chapter title}
\clearpage
Why two dots in fancy header here? No more\ldots

\end{document}
```

The reason for not including the period in `\thesection` is because it would otherwise be included in `\ref`s to a section, which might be odd, as they can occur mid-sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Compiling with Overleaf, this does seem to work nicely. It appears that ``\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}`` also adds dots after subsections and so on (this is very good). And if one wishes to have a dot after subsections in TOC as well, then ``\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}`` can be added.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED** You can use the `titlesec` package that you already loaded, to add the dot to the section number instead of redefining `\thesection`.

In a similar way after the subsection number.

I added some dummy text to check the headers generated by `fancyhdr`.

Strictly speaking, `fancyhdr` is not needed to solve the issue of the double dot. But it gives you a better control of the headers and footers.

I added part of Werner`s code to add, for sections and subsections, the dot in the TOC (last figure).

[image: s]

[image: sub]

[image: t]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[compact,explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thesection .\quad #1} % section number with dot
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thesubsection .\quad #1} % subsection number with dot  

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref} 
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

% *********************************** TOC
\usepackage{tocloft} % added to correct TOC%
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}% Add dot after section number in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}% Add dot after subsection number in ToC
% *********************************** TOC

\usepackage{kantlipsum}  % dummy text
\begin{document}
    
    {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\tableofcontents}  
    \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \chapter{My chapter title}  
    11. \kant[11-15]
    
    \section{My section title (sec)}
    12. \kant[12-16]
    
        \subsection{My subsection title (subsec)}
    14. \kant[14-18]
    
    \newpage
    Why two dots in fancy header here?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apologies for the delay. I currently do not have access to my PC, so I had to compile in Overleaf. With the ``fancypagestyle`` setup it did not compile, so I deleted that part and only kept ``\pagestyle{fancy}``. Then with your solution, the Roman numeral show up in the header, this is unwanted. One can get rid of this by adding ``\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}`` (without the dot this time). But then table of contents does not have the dot.

Comment: @Linear Christmas Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer! Now, it seems to mostly work :). Caveat: apprears that dots after subsections need to be added separately (both in text and TOC).

Comment: After 2nd edit: Yes, this now works beautifully, and generalises nicely to subsections (which were not part of OP). Thank you for your help iin this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you load titlesec, you can use its `\titlelabel` command:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}

    \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\tableofcontents}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \chapter{My chapter title}
        \section{My section title}
            \pagebreak
            Why two dots in fancy header here?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Currently, I had to compile with Overleaf (no access to my PC), apologies for delay. Three things: 1) Stray letter "A" popped into your answer :-). 2) I guess I have to add ``\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}``back if I want to get rid of the Roman numeral in header. 3) With this MWE, the dots are now missing from TOC where they ought to remain. Maybe this is an issue with older version of some package, I do not know.

Comment: @LinearChristmas: For the stray letter, sorry, it was a remnant of a first trial that I forgot to remove. For point 2), yes that's the simplest thing you can do. For the dots problem, I don't understand: I added the `\tableof contents` command, and I have  the dots for sections (not for chapters, which is typographically normal, as the page number of chapters is boldfaced).

Comment: That's OK. 3) I meant that the dots are missing in the table of contents with this solution: see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CrKT.png).

Comment: I had misunderstood what you meant. Since you load `titlesec`, you can load its companion package `titletoc`and use this code 
`\titlecontents{section}[1.45em]{}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.65pc]{.}\contentspage}`.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Yes, now your solution seems to work. I think I prefer Werner's answer the most. Otherwise, there is a bit too much manual tinkering, and repeating this with subsection (along with spacing) and so on. But thank you very much all the same.